# inline with name in returning section ignores value in Jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Looks like there is no possibility to inline value with name in returning section in Jooq 3.10

I tried such queries

```
 val role = name("role").fields("role_id")
            .`as`(select(ROLES.ROLE_ID)
                .from(ROLES)
                .where(ROLES.LEGACY_ID.eq(roleId)))
        return dsl.with(role)
            .insertInto(USER)
            .columns(
                USER.EMAIL,
                USER.ROLE_ID)
            .select(
                select(
                    inline(email),
                    role.field("role_id", Int::class.java))
                    .from(role))
            .onConflict(USER.EMAIL)
            .doNothing()
            .returning(USER.EMAIL, inline(roleId).as("role))
```

and

```
 val role = name("role").fields("role_id")
            .`as`(select(ROLES.ROLE_ID)
                .from(ROLES)
                .where(ROLES.LEGACY_ID.eq(roleId)))
        return dsl.with(role)
            .insertInto(USER)
            .columns(
                USER.EMAIL,
                USER.ROLE_ID)
            .select(
                select(
                    inline(email),
                    role.field("role_id", Int::class.java))
                    .from(role))
            .onConflict(USER.EMAIL)
            .doNothing()
            .returning(USER.EMAIL, inline(roleId))
```

In the first case it is converted into such sql

```
select 
  'new_email@expedia.com', 
   role.role_id
from role
on conflict (email) do nothing
returning 
  auction.user.email, 
  role
```

And I receive an error that there is no role field

and in the second case it is converted into

```
select 
  'new_email@expedia.com', 
   role.role_id
from role
on conflict (email) do nothing
returning 
  auction.user.email, 
  2
```

And I can't refer to the inlined column by name on fetching stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there was a known and very unfortunate limitation of that [`InsertReturningStep.returning()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertReturningStep.html#returning-org.jooq.SelectFieldOrAsterisk...-) method, it is only allowed to project columns from the table that you insert into, no expressions.

This problem was solved in jOOQ 3.11 via the new [`InsertReturningStep.returningResult()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertReturningStep.html#returningResult-org.jooq.SelectFieldOrAsterisk...-) method via issue [#1234](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7475). The original method was not retrofitted due to backwards compatibility constraints. You can now do:

```
.returningResult(USER.EMAIL, inline(roleId))
```

I don't think there's an easy way to work around this problem in jOOQ 3.11, short of converting the entire query to a [plain SQL templating query](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)